# Is it possible to access the angular velocity of an object from a driver?

Tags: python, animation, physics, drivers

Is it possible to access the angular velocity of an object from a driver script? I know how to do this in BGE but this is for an animation.

Currently I am saving the current rotation for use in the next iteration to calculate the angular displacement, however the time between iterations is variable. Before I attempt calculating the time offset, I wanted to ask if there was an API for the non BGE physics engine.

I am working on a governor for a steam engine with bob weights that swing out when rotated. The displacement of the weights is proportional to square of the angular velocity.